# Passing dict from one view controller to another via segue wont work

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsdictionary, segue

I am trying to access a dictionary from MainViewController to dataViewController.

in dataViewController i have created a property in ".h file:


    `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dataDict;`

Synthasized the file in the ".m" file


`@synthesize dataDict;`

and in the viewDidLoad method, placed this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"Time: %@", dataDict);
}
```

Now in my MainViewController i have imported into the .h file:


    `#import "dataViewController.h"`

and in the ".m" placed in ViewWillAppear:

```
dataViewController *controller = [[dataViewController alloc] init];
controller.dataDict = jsonDict;
NSLog(@"Time: %@", controller.dataDict);
```

NSLog from the MainViewController displays as it should.

NSLog from the dataViewController say NULL.

Comment: What is dataViewController ? Is it connected somehow to UIViewController ? What is an order of logs ? Which one is showing first ?

Comment: Can you post the code that set the value to jsonDict?

Comment: `NSLog(@"Time: %@", dataDict);` add this line in your viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: You are making a common (but, to me, inexplicable) mistake.  When you alloc/init dataViewController in MainViewController you're creating a new copy, unrelated to the one where you execute viewDidLoad.

Comment: MainViewController has 4 buttons across the bottom, when the button that says Data is pressed a segue is created that pushes dataViewController to the ContainerView on MainViewController.  what do i need to change in the code to make it work?

Comment: i have also tried:    dataViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.dataDict = jsonDict;
but i keep getting a [uiviewcontroller setinfo:] unrecogonised selector sent to instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed to have dataArray in the 4 different segue destination's as only one had it. so more info might have helped peeps. code that fixed the data transfer:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"graphSegue"]) {
    graphViewController *destViewController = (graphViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.dataArray = locationArray;
```